# Accessing public variables in other packages

Tags: java

So public variables can be accessed from anywhere, even from other packages. However, when I try to create an object from a foreign package, in order to get access to the public variables it contains, I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    Foo cannot be resolved to a type
```

My code:

```
Foo obj = new Foo();
```

I was wondering what is the correct way to create objects that exist in packages other than the one thats creating it?

I appreciate any help in this regard.

Comment: Please include the code you are currently using to create the object that is causing that error.

Comment: This is a compilation error. You have not imported the class Foo, seems to be.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you `import Foo;`  ?

with qualified name `com.some.package.Foo`

If you declare your class `Foo`

```
package com.mycompany.app.package1;

public class Foo{}
```

Then you need to import this type by writing

```
import com.mycompany.app.package1.Foo;
```

in any other(other than `com.some.package` ) package where `Foo` is used

---

**See**

- [Using package](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/usepkgs.html)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Can you please post an exmaple of an import for a package?